# A problem with equation nodes in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, overlays, uncover

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath, physics}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\begin{frame}
  If truncated to the second order, the KM expansion becomes the \alert{Fokker-Planck (\textbf{FP}) equation}
  \begin{equation*}
    \uncover<2->{\alt<3->{\pdv{p_{1|1}}{t}=-\pdv{}{x}\bigg(\tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=magenta!20,anchor=base] (u1) {$a_1(x,t)$};}\;p_{1|1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\pdv[2]{}{x}\bigg(\tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (u2) {$a_2(x,t)$};}\;p_{1|1}\bigg)}{\pdv{p_{1|1}}{t}=-\pdv{}{x}\bigg(a_1(x,t)\;p_{1|1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\pdv[2]{}{x}\bigg(a_2(x,t)\;p_{1|1}\bigg)}}
  \end{equation*}

  \uncover<4->{
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
      \item[] {\textcolor{magenta}{drift} coefficient}
            \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (l1) {};
    \end{itemize}
  
  \begin{flushright}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
      \item[] {\alert{diffusion} coefficient}
            \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (l2) {};
    \end{itemize}
  \end{flushright}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->] (l1) edge [bend right] (u1);
    \path[->] (l2) edge [bend right] (u2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Essentially, I would like to connect the arrows `(l1)` and `(l2)` to the nodes `(n1)` and `(n2)` of an equation, but it doesn't recognize them because they're out of scope. I tried to modify the code, but I'm just making things worse...

Comment: Have a look at the `tikzmarks` library

Comment: And please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Have a look at `\tikzset` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want to use nodes from other tikzpictures, you should use the `remember picture` option
- you must not draw your arrow on overlays on which you don't define the nodes. If you use `\alt`, `\uncover` etc to only define the nodes on some of your overlays, you must not draw your arrows on the other overlays.
- instead of repeating your equation multiple times with and without the boxes, use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to define on which overlays the fill colour shall be visible
- I suggest to have a look at the `tikzmarks` library. This way you wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel
- a lot of the packages you load are unnecessary. You should clean up your preamble and only load the package which you need for your presentation.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      
%  \usecolortheme{default} 
%  \usefonttheme{default} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, 
%amsmath, 
physics}

\tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  If truncated to the second order, the KM expansion becomes the \alert{Fokker-Planck (\textbf{FP}) equation}
  \begin{equation*}
    \uncover<2->{\pdv{p_{1|1}}{t}=-\pdv{}{x}\bigg(\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{
            \node[fill=magenta!20,anchor=base,fill on=<3->] (u1) {$a_1(x,t)$};}\;p_{1|1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\pdv[2]{}{x}\bigg(\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base,fill on=<3->] (u2) {$a_2(x,t)$};}\;p_{1|1}\bigg)}
  \end{equation*}

  \uncover<4->{
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
      \item[] {\textcolor{magenta}{drift} coefficient}
            \tikz[na,remember picture] \node[coordinate] (l1) {};
    \end{itemize}
  
%  \begin{flushright}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
      \item[] {\alert{diffusion} coefficient}
            \tikz[na,remember picture] \node[coordinate] (l2) {};
    \end{itemize}
%  \end{flushright}

\begin{onlyenv}<4->
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path[->] (l1) edge [bend right] (u1);
    \path[->] (l2) edge [bend right] (u2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that it doesn't recognize `/tikz/fill on`?

Comment: @ric.san Not if you added `overlay-beamer-styles` like in my answer

Comment: I added it in the preamble, but the error keeps showing up

Comment: Then you should ask a new question about this problem, including a MWE and the complete .log file

Comment: You should mention the TeXLive `aobs-tikz` package.

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's why I would like to see the complete .log file :)

Comment: @ric.san The [CTAN package `aobs-tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) that provides the `overlay-beamer-styles` library hasn't been updated since 2014. Either you've got an even older version of it (if it exists) or you should already have gotten an error message when trying to `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}`.

Comment: Solved, thank you all, and especially @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz